# How do I label nodes in a Tree in Haskell?

Tags: algorithm, haskell, functional-programming, tree

Say that I have a `Data.Tree` holding characters: `Tree Char`:

```
    A
   / \
  B   C
     /|\
    D A F
```

Note that in the tree there could be duplicates. I want to store this tree in a relational DB by storing edges but I cannot use the content of the node as the key because of the duplicates (note the `A` at different levels).

Maybe a solution is to traverse de tree and map it with unique ids like:

```
    (1,A)
    / \
 (2,B) (3,C)
        /|\
  (4,D)(5,A),(6,F)
```

Now storing the edges hasn't any problem because I use the ids.

```
(1, null, A)
(2, 1, B)
(3, 1, C)
(4, 3, D)
(5, 3, A)
(6, 3, F)
```

But I cannot see how to "map" the static tree nodes to an infinite id generator.

What would be your approach from a functional point of view? Note that I cannot make any assumptions on the arity of the branching factor, so I cannot flatten, zip with ids, and reconstruct the tree

Comment: You could make your `Tree` type transformer an instance of the `Traversable` class, then use [`mapAccumL`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.16.0.0/docs/Data-List.html#v:mapAccumL) to get a second tree adorned with node ids.

Comment: Do you want depth first or breadth first traversal? Your example is ambiguous in that respect.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can work with a `State` that will dispatch ids, so:

```
import Control.Monad.State.Lazy(State, get, put)

labelNext :: State Int Int
labelNext = do
    val <- get
    put (val+1)
    return val
```

Then we can label the tree with:

```
{-# LANGUAGE TupleSections #-}

labelTree :: Tree a -> Tree (Int, a)
labelTree tree = evalState (traverse (\a -> (,a) <$> labelNext) tree) 1
```

This for example gives us:

```
ghci> labelTree (Node 'A' [Node 'B' [], Node 'C' [Node 'D' [], Node 'A' [], Node 'F' []]])
Node {rootLabel = (1,'A'), subForest = [Node {rootLabel = (2,'B'), subForest = []},Node {rootLabel = (3,'C'), subForest = [Node {rootLabel = (4,'D'), subForest = []},Node {rootLabel = (5,'A'), subForest = []},Node {rootLabel = (6,'F'), subForest = []}]}]}
```